# How can I output a counter or/and progress bar in the UI?

Tags: python, interface

When I batch operations such as exportings, I'd like to know when it will be over.

Having a progress bar or indicator and something like "X of Y" (X is number of objects processed; Y is total number of objects) would be useful.

Does Blender have a way to accomplish this?